# Drop Down Refresh not working?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, pull-to-refresh

I've successfully implemented a drop down refresh into my rss feed so that when I pull down the `UITableView`, it should refresh. All is well in that sense as the date on the pull down refreshes etc. but my `UITableView` doesn't refresh.

I've followed this code: [DropDownRefresh](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh).

Am I missing something to actually refresh the tableview?

Thanks.

**Refresh Code**

```
- (void)reloadTableViewDataSource {

//should be calling your tableviews data source model to reload.
//put here just for demo.
[self performSelector:@selector(refresh)];
_reloading = YES;
}

- (void)refresh {

for (NSString *feed in _feeds) {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:feed];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [_queue addOperation:request];
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you implementing the delegate methods:

```
 #pragma mark EGORefreshTableHeaderDelegate Methods

 - (void)egoRefreshTableHeaderDidTriggerRefresh:(EGORefreshTableHeaderView*)view{

     [self reloadTableViewDataSource];
     [self performSelector:@selector(doneLoadingTableViewData) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];

 }
```

Have a look at the Demo example ([View folder](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh/tree/master/Demo/TableViewPull/Classes/View/RefreshTableHeaderView)) for more details.

Comment: I seem to have done it. Please check above to see if it's correct. It does refresh now. Thanks.

Comment: I think that also calling `reloadData` on your `UITableView` should work.

Comment: Sergio, seems like when I refresh, the new tweets duplicate. So I posted a tweet and then refresh. The tableview shows that new tweet. I refresh again, and the tweet duplicates. If I refresh again, theres 3 of the same tweet showing. Do you know why? My refresh method is above. Thanks.

Comment: If you read all the feeds each time, you should empty your table data source beforehand. I think you should do that at the beginning of your refresh method.

Comment: How can I empty my table data source? I'm not too sure. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know how your data source is implemented. What does you ASIHTTP delegate do when it gets some data? store it in some NSArray? then simply call `removeAllObjects` on it...

Comment: @sergio let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1207/discussion-between-k-honda-and-sergio)

Comment: Sergio, I'm not too sure either. I used this rss tutorial. [RSS Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2636/how-to-make-a-simple-rss-reader-iphone-app-tutorial) Thanks.

Comment: As far as I understand from the tutorial, if you call `[self.allEntries removeAllObjects];`, it should work for you. I suppose that the refresh method is in the controller class that also has got the `_entries` ivar.

Comment: I put `self.allEntries removeAllObjects` in `reloadTableViewDataSource` and then called `refresh` after but then it crashes in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` at this line `RSSEntry *entry = [_allEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: put `[self.tableView reloadData];` after `removeAllObjects` line.

Comment: It doesn't crash now, but after the refresh the tableview is empty. All the RSS feeds have gone and so it shows empty cells. Do you know why? Thanks.

Comment: Try to put those lines (removeAllObject/reload) at the beginning of your `requestFinished` method. Reload is possibly not strictly necessary in this case. Anyway, this will work only in case you manage just on feed, otherwise you will need a method to clean up your table in a more controlled way.

Comment: It's not working Sergio. Nevermind, thanks for your help. I'll try other ways.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you've got the following code so far:

```
- (void)reloadTableViewDataSource
{
  //  should be calling your tableviews data source model to reload
  //  put here just for demo
  _reloading = YES;
}
```

So you might do something like:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

to trigger a reload of the table's cells.

Comment: I think I have done it. I've posted the code above. See if it looks ok. Thanks.